# Custom Multer storage - Illegal operation when using Sharp

Tags: node.js, multer, sharp

I'm using [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) together with [Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) to store images uploaded as part of an HTML form. I want to resize and transform the images before storing them on the disk and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455054) thread about how to do just that.

I thought I had set-up everything correctly, but when I try and upload an image I get:

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\...\uploads'

Below is my code:

Routes.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var customStorage = require(path.join(__dirname, 'customStorage.js'));

var upload = multer({
    storage: new customStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'));
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now());
        }
    }),
    limits: { fileSize: 5000000 }
});
...
app.use('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => { ... });
```

customStorage.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sharp = require('sharp');

function getDestination (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/dev/null'); // >Implying I use loonix
};

function customStorage (opts) {
    this.getDestination = (opts.destination || getDestination);
};

customStorage.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile(req, file, cb) {
    this.getDestination(req, file, function (err, path) {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        var transform = sharp().resize(200, 200).background('white').embed().jpeg();

        file.stream.pipe(transform).pipe(outStream);
        outStream.on('error', cb);
        outStream.on('finish', function () {
            cb(null, {
                path: path,
                size: outStream.bytesWritten
            });
        });
    });
};

customStorage.prototype._removeFile = function _removeFile(req, file, cb) {
    fs.unlink(file.path, cb);
};

module.exports = function (opts) {
    return new customStorage(opts);
};
```

Comment: Is there any more information in the error you receive, such as a specific line where the error is being thrown?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Can you console log `path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')` inside the `destination` function in _Routes.js_?

Comment: customStorage.js: https://i.imgur.com/EDO7Wgm.png

Routes.js: `Path: C:\Users\lolechi\Desktop\nosos\public\rooms`

I lied a little and said that the images are uploaded to `uploads` but they're actually uploaded to `public\rooms`.

Comment: Does this directory already exist before you run the code? If so, try changing the path name to a directory that doesn't exist (maybe `C:\Users\lolechi\Desktop\nosos\public\uploads`) and see if it works.

I _think_ Multer requires that it creates a new directory as it runs.

Comment: Also make sure the path has a `/` at the end, just in case (that's what they do in the Multer docs).

Comment: I deleted the `rooms` directory and Multer just created a file called `rooms` that was the uploaded image. I think the problem is that the path being passed doesn't include the desired filename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165310/discussion-between-223seneca-and-lolechi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory** in this context indicates that you are setting Multer's destination to a directory when it should be the name of the destination file.

The destination is set in the line `cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'));` in *Routes.js*. If you change this line to something like `cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'myDirectory\\mySubdirectory\\', myFilename + '.jpg'))`, it will work.